# Javascript conditional not alerting when its condition is reached

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I made a for loop in `game()` function to have the user input rock, paper, or scissors. If the game is played 5 times the loop is supposed to alert "You played 5 games already" but it doesn't alert when the condition is met. I tried adding return before alert, I also tried using >= instead of === but it doesn't work.

```
function game(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(i < 5){
            let getSelect = prompt("Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors", "");
            let getWinOrLose = alert(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
                if( i === 5 ){
                    alert("You played 5 games already");
                }
        }
    }
}

console.log(game());
```

Check the code above ^

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JaredDev/cbmLetuz/2/

Comment: With `for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++)` loop is guaranteed to stop when i is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won´t show the alert because condition `i===5` is never reached since it is guarded by `i<5`. Plus the loop never reaches value of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try `for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {` the loop will run until `i` is less or equal to 5 and should trigger the `i === 5` condition.

Just be aware that the loop will run 6 times for the `i` values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 so you may want to consider tweaking the numbers to your specs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `i===5`. Since, It is `i < 5`, The condition satisfies during `i===4` itself. So change `i===5` to `i===4`. As like the code given below,

```
function game(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(i < 5){
            let getSelect = prompt("Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors", "");
            let getWinOrLose = alert(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
                if( i === 4 ){
                    alert("You played 5 games already");
                }
        }
    }
}

console.log(game());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is below:

```
 if( i === 4 ){
    alert("You played 5 games already");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop increment is limited to <5 means 4 only. and condition says i===5 means I can never be 5 in above case